# How to convert a Tensor to Eager tensor in Tensorflow 2.1.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I've been trying to convert a tensor of type:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor
```

to an eagertensor:

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
```

I've been searching for a solution but couldn't find one. Any help would be appreciated.

**Context:**

I have obtained the tensor using the feature extraction method from a Keras Sequential model. The output was a tensor of the first mentioned type.
However, when I tried to convert it to numpy using .numpy(), it did not work with the following error:

```
'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

But then when I try creating a tensor using tf.constant and then using .numpy() to convert it, it works fine!

The only difference I found is that the types of tensors are different:
The tensor generated by Keras sequential is of the first type mentionned above, whereas the second tensor that I have created manually is of the second type (Eager tensor).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568041/tensorflow-how-do-i-convert-a-eagertensor-into-a-numpy-array

Comment: Well, basically I want to convert to Eagertensor so that I can use .numpy().

Comment: I have added context to my question, I don't know if that would help.

Comment: `EagerTensor`s are implicitly converted to `Tensor`s. More accurately, a new `Tensor` object is created and the values are copied into the new tensor. TF doesn't modify tensor contents at all; it always creates new Tensors. The type of the new tensor depends on if the line creating it is executing in Eager mode.

Comment: I understand, but then why would the ```.numpy()``` not work?

Comment: Kindly share a reproducible code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing one more answer as the same error appears on different scenario.

The error you are getting is because of version issue .i.e. `tensorflow version 2.1.0`. I ran the code by skipping the first 2 paragraphs that is to install `tensorflow==2.1.0` and `keras==2.3.1` and the error didn't reappear.

Your issue vanishes in the latest version of the `tensorflow version 2.3.0`. Run the program on latest versions, that means do not install tensorflow and keras again because Google Colab already has the latest and stable version pre installed.

```
features.numpy()
```

**Output -**

```
array([[0.       , 0.3728346, 0.       , ..., 1.0103987, 0.       ,
        0.4194043]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2):

Could have answered better if you would have shared the reproducible code.

Below is a simple scenario where I have recreated your error. Here I am reading the path of a image file.

**Code to recreate the error:**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def get_path(file_path):
    print("file_path: ", bytes.decode(file_path.numpy()),type(bytes.decode(file_path.numpy())))
    return file_path

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/bird.png')
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: (get_path(x)))

for one_element in train_dataset:
    print(one_element)
```

**Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2d5db8425f67> in <module>()
      8 
      9 train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/bird.png')
---> 10 train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: (get_path(x)))
     11 
     12 for one_element in train_dataset:

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    256       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    257         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 258           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    259         else:
    260           raise

AttributeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-8-2d5db8425f67>:10 None  *
        train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: (get_path(x)))
    <ipython-input-8-2d5db8425f67>:6 get_path  *
        print("file_path: ", bytes.decode(file_path.numpy()),type(bytes.decode(file_path.numpy())))

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Below are the steps I have implemented in the code to fix this error.

1. Have decorated the map function with `tf.py_function(get_path, [x], [tf.string])`. You can find more about tf.py_function [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function).
2. Now I can get the string part by using `bytes.decode(file_path.numpy())` in map function.

**Fixed Code:**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def get_path(file_path):
    print("file_path: ",bytes.decode(file_path.numpy()),type(bytes.decode(file_path.numpy())))
    return file_path

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/content/bird.jpg')
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(get_path, [x], [tf.string]))

for one_element in train_dataset:
    print(one_element)
```

**Output:**

```
file_path:  /content/bird.jpg <class 'str'>
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'/content/bird.jpg'>,)
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I think the error I am getting is due to something else, here is a colab notebook to reproduce the error in similar condition:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1m1sKw0bkU_sns_tnHqgVPnUUmausucoB?usp=sharing

Comment: @hamza-boulahia - I had look into your code, writing one more answer as a solution for your problem.